# Change order of Zend Framework 2 DateSelect drop downs

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a form element in a ZF2 application that uses DateSelect to allow a user to enter their date of birth. Currently the fields are shown in the order d-m-y. I would like to reverse this order so it is displayed as y-m-d. I have come across posts on SO that recommend changing the locale in PHP to change the order but that is not an option for me. I have also tried

```
 $this->add(array(
        'type'    => 'Zend\Form\Element\DateSelect',
        'name'    => 'dob',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Date of Birth',
            'create_empty_option' => true,
            'pattern' => $this->options['isMobile'] ? 'd MMM y' : 'd MMM y',
            'empty_options' => array(
                'day' => 'DD',
                'month' => 'MM',
                'year' => 'YYYY',
            ),
            'allowLabelHTML' => TRUE,
            'required' => true,
        )
    ));
    $this->get('dob')->setFormat('Y-m-d');
```

Which was an accepted answer to another SO question but that produces an internal server error for me. I would be surprised if this is not possible, maybe using an helper file but I cannot find anything on the web to suggest how, apart from the above and changing the locale. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: find text of error in log files

Comment: It is a 'call to undefined method'  error.

Answer (score 1):

You get fatal error because method `setFormat()` does not exist in `Zend\Form\Element\DateSelect`.
I don't think it is possible to achieve this without writing own view helper.

`Zend\Form\Element\DateSelect` is based on locale settings, so you can pass locale short code as parameter to view helper, so order of elements will be proper for provided region.

This view helper takes 3 parameters `$this->formDateSelect($element, $intlFormat, $locale)`, so you use it like this:

`echo $this->formDateSelect($form->get('dob'), \IntlDateFormatter::LONG, 'en_Gb');`

or...
`echo $this->formDateSelect()->setLocale('en_Gb')->render($form->get('dob'));`

or... you can change locale settings in your `php.ini` file

> intl.default_locale = en_Gb

Comment: I'll need to check this SzymonM but it seems to be the correct approach. Thank you